# How to determine the variety of an ideal?

Tags: ideals, affine-varieties

I have the ideal:
I:= {P ∈ ℚ [x,y] | P(5,0) = P(1,1) = 0}. Which I have proven is an ideal and now I am unsure how to answer the following questions.

1: Determine the variety V (I) associated with I. Justify your answer.
2: Give an example of a set S ⊂ ℚ  such that
 V(I(S)) ≠ S.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What work have you done so far? Additionally, do you know what relationship there is between $V(I(S))$ and $S$ generically?

Comment: In my notes I have in general that if $f^{m} \elemnt I(x)$ then $f^{m}(v)=0$ for all $ v \elemnt x$